# Rebuild a GIT repo from an existing clone

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to rebuild a git repo from an existing clone using the steps below:

```
git init --bare project.git
git remote add project project.git
git push --all project
```

I noticed that this does not push all the branches. It only pushes the master branch.

I do not want to repeat this process for every branch. Is there a single command to
accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: You either have the `.git` directory or not, if not you have lost all the other branches, if you have it you don't need to init again.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone with the `--mirror` option the other way. Then just copy the repo. If you need to push all of them and they are not set up for tracking you can:

```
git checkout HEAD
```

become headless so you don't have the asterix in the branch output.

```
git branch | xargs git push origin
```

use xargs to put each branch as an argument to `git push origin`. Optionally add `-u` to set up tracking so next time you can just `git push` to sync up.